# Pynput ignore key held

Tags: python, keyboard-events, pynput

I have a program that prints time elapsed when a user first presses and holds down a key and prints again when the key is released. If after 5 seconds, the user presses and holds the up arrow on their keyboard for 3 seconds before releasing, the program should print "0:05 response 1 ON" and then "0:08 response 1 OFF". The problem I'm having is that holding down the key registers as multiple key presses, resulting in the time being printed multiple times per second. Any ideas how to treat a key being pressed and held as a single key press?

```
import time
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

f = open("quick_data.txt", "a")
f.write(time.ctime() + "\n")

def show(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.enter:
        global start
        start = time.perf_counter()
    if key == keyboard.Key.delete:
        return False
    if key == keyboard.Key.up:
        elapsed = time.perf_counter()
        x = time.gmtime(elapsed - start)
        y = time.strftime('%M:%S', x)
        f.write(str(y) + " response 1 ON" + "\n")

def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.up:
        elapsed = time.perf_counter()
        x = time.gmtime(elapsed - start)
        y = time.strftime('%M:%S', x)
        f.write(str(y) + " response 1 OFF" + "\n")

with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=show,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

The library does not natively provide key press holding support, but you can easily utilize a timer to emulate said functionality.

Just initiate a timer at the start to register the time when the key associated with `"RESPONSE 1"` was pressed. If the new key input's time differs from the last keypress's time by more than the threshold, then it's (probably) a new keypress, and hence you write to the file "response 1 ON". Then you reset the time of the last detected keypress of `RESPONSE 1` to ensure the keypress algorithm is in sync. When you release the key, `on_release` triggers and completes the pair. Of course, you can adjust and augment the threshold to suit your specific needs.

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

f = open("quick_data.txt", "a")
f.write(time.ctime() + "\n")
pushdown_up = time.perf_counter() # initialize variable to store the time when the key associated with RESPONSE 1 was pressed
def show(key):
    threshold = 0.10 # threshold for input timing to differentiate between a key being held and a new key
    if key == keyboard.Key.enter:
        global start
        start = time.perf_counter()
        print(start)
    if key == keyboard.Key.delete:
        return False
    if key == keyboard.Key.up:
        elapsed = time.perf_counter() 
        global pushdown_up # time of last detected keypress
        if elapsed - pushdown_up < threshold:
            # if another INPUT 1 press is detected again within a short threshold, then it is probably part of the current input press
            pass
        else: # else, then it is a start of a new input.
            x = time.gmtime(elapsed - start)
            y = time.strftime('%M:%S', x)
            f.write(str(y) + " response 1 ON" + "\n")
            print(str(y) + " response 1 ON" + "\n")
        pushdown_up = elapsed # set the last registered keypress's time\

def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.up:
        elapsed = time.perf_counter()
        x = time.gmtime(elapsed - start)
        y = time.strftime('%M:%S', x)
        f.write(str(y) + " response 1 OFF" + "\n")
        print(str(y) + " response 1 OFF" + "\n")

with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=show,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```